# Why is the 'a cat may look at a king' quote relevant for when Dr. Rohmer is looking at the man on the podium?

Tags: the-view-from-saturday, e-l-konigsburg

In *The View From Saturday*, chapter 2 (page 22 in my copy), there's this quote:

> On her left sat Dr. Roy Clayton Rohmer, the District Superintendent for Clarion Academy. Both Dr. Rohmer and Mrs. Olinski paid strict attention to the man at the podium. There could be no mistake: This was the man of the hour, king for the day.
>   He wore a navy blue, precision fit pin-striped suit and a white-on-dazzling-white shirt. An edge of his French cuffs showed beneath his jacket sleeves. Mrs. Olinski was not sure how much the correct amount was, but if she put a spirit-level to his, they would be exactly right. The French cuffs were held together with onyx cuff links, and his collar was tied with a red-striped power necktie. The television lights beamed down on his crop of hair, which was tinted the color of peach pits. He was dressed, brushed, coiffed, and blow-dried not just to be seen but to be looked at.
>
> Dr. Rohmer could not, would not take his eyes off the man at the podium, and Mrs. Olinski thought of *Alice in Wonderland*. "Don't look at me like that!" said the King to the Cheshire Cat. "A cat may look at a King," said Alice. Mrs. Olinski wanted to tell Dr. Rohmer that a cat may look at a king. But why bother? The audience was not permitted to speak.

I'm having trouble understanding why that would be an appropriate quote to mention. Nobody told him that he couldn't look, and he's obviously doing it, so why would Mrs. Olinski want to tell him that?

Comment: The important contextual point is *why* is Dr. Rohmer looking at the man? Who is the man? What is he saying? Does he have any relationship to Dr. Rohmer? Does Dr. Rohmer blame him for something? "A cat may look at a king" essentially means that even the smallest and humblest has basic rights. Is Mrs. Olinski trying to offer him solace or support?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - I'll edit in the proceeding text, which should answer those questions.

Comment: Without having read the book, I interpret it like this: The picture of Dr. R looking at the man at the podium reminds Mrs. O of the cat looking at the king, just because of how intent Dr. R is and how kingly the MATP appears. But since the audience isn't allowed to talk, Mrs. O wants to remind Dr. R that yeah, he can look, but it's not going to do him any good, since it's the only "right" available to him.